# Building custom where clause with dynamic column input LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In the below lambda expression, i have three columns in where clause , that may differ based on the input which i get from database, if it was a static list i could have built the expression as below, but it is dynamic so i need to add the where clause dynamically, the number of columns i have in where clause would be equal to the number of items in the list. so i need to build a loop or something, how will i accomplish it.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (Convert.ToDecimal(x["Total"]) <= list[0] && Convert.ToDecimal(x["bal"]) <= list[1] && Convert.ToDecimal(x["issued"]) <= list[2])).ToList().Count;
```

Comment: Please explain the `3` in the first row of the output, which rows did you count? There's only 2 values less than 2 in the input table, 0.8 and 1.6.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen-i have now edited the question, i also included the row which is equal to that , i,e the same row from input table

Comment: if you would use query instead of linq it would be: select t2.*, (select count(*) from table1 where columnYouSearch<=compareValue) as Count from table2 t2

Comment: @virusivv-its  dynamic datatable created, should be done in c# only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to make the linq dynamic

```
 var dynamicQuery = dt.AsEnumerable(); //to add dynamic where clause, first convert datatable to enumerable.
                    foreach(string name in columnName) //maintaining column names in a seperate list, as list would be dynamic
                    {
                        dynamicQuery = dynamicQuery.Where(r => (Convert.ToDecimal(r[name]) <= list[columnName.IndexOf(name)]));
                    }
                    int count=dynamicQuery.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a dictionary

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //get a dictionary the contains a double as a key and the value
            // the count of the number of times the key occurs
            Dictionary<double, int> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<double>("Total"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList().Count);
            //sample number of key to lookup
            double num = 778.660;
            //get the number of times the key appears in the input data.
            int count = dict[num];
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: @jdweng-the solution is unclear,it does not work, moreover the colums are hardcoded, can it not be done using column index as i will be having the column indexes, but not sure on the number of columns.